# Open or close an open windows-file using Java

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems

I'm new to Stackoverflow and generally to programming forums, so please forgive me if I haven't post my question as expected :).

I also tried searching for an answer for an hour and surprisingly couldn't find anything useful.

I'm writing a code to move a windows file to another folder by using inputfilestream. the problem is, when the file is opened in windows (and it must be in some cases) opening a new file ans assigning it to the inputfilestream fails:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\N\Desktop\source\Doc1.docx (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.init>(Unknown Source)

and so I figured out that trying opening a file stream, I must make sure it is closed. 
but I can't find the way to close a windows file through Java code.
all I could find regarded java.nio.File, which is virtual and does not have a close method. how then do I do it?
can anyone help me find a reference of such an action?

my relevant piece of code:

```
    private void moveFileToFolder(File sourceDir, File destDir, Path prevFileName, String newFileName){
    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
        try{
            try{ //wait so windows can close file successfully 
                //(if it was opened as a new file and then closed automatically) before trying to read from it
                wait(1000);
            }catch(Exception e ){}
            File source =new File(sourceDir.getPath() + "\\" + prevFileName);
            File dest =new File(destDir.getPath() + "\\" + newFileName);

            inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            source.delete();
            if (DEBUG_MODE){
                System.out.println("File was copied successfully!");
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much!
Noa

Answer (score 1):

If a File is opened you won't be able to close it via Java because, in order to close it, you would have to have it opened in your Java code.

What you can do is to create a list and add all Files that have failed and then at the end of your processing try to process those Files again.

If it still fails the user may be using it, so it is interesting to prompt for user help or log this to a log file so that the user can get the information of what Files wasn't processed.

Answer (score 1):

open close and delete window files using java...

```
    final File file=new File("E:\\features.xlsx");

    //open file
    if(file.exists())
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start E:\\"+file.getName());

    //close and delete a open file
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "cmd /c taskkill /f /im excel.exe");  //put "winword.exe" for ms word file

     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                  Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                  file.delete();    

               } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
              } 
        }
    }).start();
```